# Are there (have there been) any efforts to create a schema language for arbitrary binary formats?

Tags: binary

XML has a lot of benefits. It's both machine and human readable, it has a standardized format and it is remarkably versatile.

It also has some disadvantages. It's verbose and not a very efficient means of transferring large amounts of data.

One of the most useful aspects of XML is the schema language. Using a schema you can generate source code in any modern programming language to read an xml format without the tedious process of hand coding that usually accompanies most other file formats.

This got me thinking about whether a schema language for arbitrary binary file formats exists and if not, would it be a worth while endeavor?

Just in case I've been unclear. I'm asking about a language whose purpose is to define byte offsets, field and record lengths, delimiters, etc. that could be parsed to generate code that would read a file format that conformed to that specification.

I doubt I'm the first to suggest such an idea so if you know of any projects or working groups that have or are currently pursuing this area I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question, but in the last few years I feel that Kaitai Struct has emerged as one of the best arbitrary binary schema description options, the bonus that it generates parsing code is a huge bonus.

https://kaitai.io/

"develop parsers for binary structures"

Answer (score 2):

Yes, several people have tried to do this.

One such attempt is [Binary Format Description](http://collaboratory.emsl.pnl.gov/sam/bfd/). Another is [Data Format Description Language](http://forge.gridforum.org/projects/dfdl-wg). I'm not sure how practical either one really is, though.

Comment: There's also BinX, the Binary XML description language: http://www.edikt.org.uk/binx/

Answer (score 1):

xtype is a new general-purpose binary data language I developed that also covers the typical usage of XML: https://github.com/bitagoras/xtype/
A similar format that should be mentioned here is UBJSON, an efficient binary format for JSON like structures: https://github.com/ubjson/universal-binary-json

Answer (score 0):

"schema" and "arbitrary" are contradictory.  Specifying byte offsets, field and record lengths, delimiters, etc. is not "arbitrary".

Byte offsets have been around since COBOL.  EDI is a well known, tried and true protocol that does exactly this.

WebMethods, an EDI tool, has a very nice EDI parser built into it.

Comment: "Specifying byte offsets, field and record lengths, delimiters, etc. is not "arbitrary"." No, but the file format defined by such a specification is. Perhaps "General Purpose" would have been a better choice of words. If you are referring to EDI as specified by the X12 standards I was looking for something a little less bureaucratic. Anybody can create and use an xml schema without needing to submit it to a standards body for approval.

Comment: But you do have to communicate it to consumers.  Even having meta-data built in doesn't mean it's always clear and understandable.  Every company that uses record-based protocols is free to create one without submitting it to a standards body; they do have to clue in consumers so they don't have to guess.

Answer (score 0):

In short, no. Unless you count programming languages as "schema languages". XML is very structured regardless of the schema. Binary formats can be absolutely anything. Consider the old MS office formats where it was essentially a memory dump of the raw data structures used at runtime. If you allow programming languages, then you can - and do - create a parser in that :-) What about compressed binary files: zip, jpeg, WebM? How and why would a schema language want to encompass those type of things?

Comment: Granted, some binary formats may be to complex to formally define using a declarative language. The same is true for some xml formats.

Comment: The why is pretty obvious to me, so you can open up the file and see the important bits that you are able to fiddle with without breaking it.  Metadata for example.  Also, zip is a well defined format.  The editor "010 Editor" provides an implementation of what the OP here is looking for and comes with some example scripts including one that parses zip files.

Answer (score 0):

Project Epidal.BeeSchema seems to fit your requirements.

https://github.com/Epidal/BeeSchema